# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать

Tags: грамматика, родительный-или-винительный

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее сказать: "купить мёртвых душ" или "купить мёртвые души"?

Answer (score 1):

> **КУПИТЬ** — 1. *что* (полный охват предмета действием).   Купить билеты в театр; Купить марку для отправки письма. 2. *чего* 
>   (частичный охват предмета действием). Купить в булочной хлеба;  Купить
>   чаю и сахару; Пойду в Гостиный двор, куплю холста (Остр.). ...

Выбор варианта зависит от контекста. Если в продаже было множество всяких мёртвых душ, а вы прикупили парочку из них, тогда "купил мёртвых душ"; если же, скажем, в продаже были живые, мёртвые и переходные формы душ, а вы купили все мёртвые — тогда "купил мёртвые души".